# Diff-patch algorithms

Tags: over-the-air-updates

I am studying about incremental programming of **restricted (low power)** IoT devices and discovered that many diff algorithms have been introduced by the literature (DASA, R3DIFF, DG, etc).

Trying them out, I found out that xdelta generally produces smaller patches. Hence the evident question is the following: Is xdelta suitable for such an environment and If yes, why do you believe the authors did not simply use xdelta algorithm for their applicationws (and instead developed other diff algorithms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share a link to the paper you are alluding to when you mention the authors. Perhaps someone can then think of something specific.
Otherwise, the general answer is "creating something new maybe better for a thesis than to say 'there exists something already' " !!